# Setting ImportRange on a delay

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Is it possible to set a timer or delay for the importrange function on Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear what you mean by "timer or delay"? How do you expect that timer should work? Have you made any search/research effort?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want this:

`=IF(NOW()>DATEVALUE("11/13/18")+TIMEVALUE("10:00 AM"),IMPORTRANGE(...),"")`